# Try the combination of setTimeout function and .load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have a problem with the following code. I want to show the index of a file (test.txt) as it changes.
While it works using Mozilla,with IE9 it seems that the settimeout() doesn't work.

```
<div id="auto">xxx</div> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#auto').load('test.txt');
    refresh1();
  });

  function refresh1() {
    setTimeout ( function() {
      $('#auto').load('test.txt');
      refresh1();
    },200);     
  }
</script>
```

I used "meta" in order to prevent IE cashing but still no success. I used

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

My problem can be solved if I leave IE aside and use Mozilla where the above code works, but there the problem is that I can't find a way(an example is much appreciated) to read/write a file using Mozilla. Is the there ActiveX equivalent for Mozilla/ Chrome? I tried some code with OSFile but no luck. I would like to avoid changing browser however. If we could find a solution using IE to read context of a "changing" file WITHOUT PAGE REFRESH I would be very happy :)

Comment: why don't you use setInterval?

Comment: Probably because the code to execute has a run time greater than the timeout.

Comment: Use your developer tools to check whether text.txt is being retrieved properly each time. IE9 may be caching it.

Comment: @AdrianWragg Good point.  The query to load the file will need some kind of unique item on the end to prevent caching. (Current time or something)... not that this solves the timeout issue

Comment: Could be security settings that differs between the browsers as well.

Comment: @Richard I'm thinking that the timeout **is** working, it's just reading the same content each time.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `complete` callback to wait for the response, before calling `refresh` again. Also consider to refresh a little bit slower, say 2 seconds.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  refresh1();
});

function refresh1(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
  // will be used as the complete callback
  setTimeout ( function() {
    $('#auto').load('test.txt', refresh1);
  }, 200);     
}
```

Edit: IE may also cache your request intentionally, either respond with a `Pragma: no-cache` header, or use `jQuery.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });` before document.ready or as said in a comment use `.load('test.txt?' + new Date().getTime(), refresh1)`.

Reference:

- http://api.jquery.com/load/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    reload_interval = setInterval(function() {
       $('#auto').load('test.txt');
    }, 200) 
}
```

That should work even in IE.

Answer (score 0):

A complete jquery solution

```
$('myElement').delay(200).queue(function( nxt ) {
    $(this).load('test.txt');
    nxt();
});
```

jQuery docs links - [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) , [queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)

Cheers!!